# Button in asp.net doesn't work sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, button

I have a textbox and a button in my code.The button when clicked should validate the value entered in the textbox.The button most of the times does it but at times doesn't do anything at all.Any help would be appreciated.

```
<asp:Button ValidationGroup="vgpPno" runat="server" ID="btnSubmitPartNumber" OnClick="btnSubmitPartNumber_Click" SkinID="MSWButton" Text="OK" OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate(){startPLI();}meta:resourcekey="btnSubmitPartNumberResource1" /> 

 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ValidationGroup="vgpPno" SkinID="MSWTextBox"
  ID="tbPARTNUMBER" MaxLength="11" meta:resourcekey="tbPARTNUMBERResource1" Width="230" Style="display: inline" CssClass="form-control input-sm"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: @shruthi please post startPLI  method also

Comment: And also the text of the textbox doesn't change on click of the button the time it doesnt work

Comment: The code for startPLI is really big and works fine.I will still post it here.

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal: try adding `CausesValidation=true` in the button and check.

Comment: The code is too big to be posted as a comment.

Comment: No still doesn't work.Once in 10 trials the button doesnt work.

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal: You need to post all the code related to this in question section, so that we can get an idea of what's exactly happening. Or else post your code here https://jsfiddle.net/ and paste the link

Comment: @NK https://jsfiddle.net/uc0wb6u1/1/

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal: Update your button code with this and try `<asp:Button ValidationGroup="vgpPno" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" ID="btnSubmitPartNumber" 
    OnClick="btnSubmitPartNumber_Click" SkinID="MSWButton" Text="OK" 
    OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate(){startPLI();}meta:resourcekey=btnSubmitPartNumberResource1" />`

Comment: No this doesn't seem to work. I added an alert in onclientclick. I don't get the alert also when I click on the button. And the text of the textbox also doesn't change. The button works fine most of the times though.

Comment: @ShrutiAgarwal: why have u written all `if(Page_ClientValidate(){startPLI();}meta:resourcekey=btnSubmitPartNumberResource1` I just used `startPLI()` and got the alert. Is there any special reason for using that ?

Comment: startPLI() should only work if all the validations are true. That is why the if condition is needed

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:Button ValidationGroup="vgpPno" runat="server" ID="btnSubmitPartNumber" OnClick="btnSubmitPartNumber_Click" SkinID="MSWButton" Text="OK" 
            OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate(){startPLI();}meta:resourcekey='btnSubmitPartNumberResource1'" />
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Check Your web Form. If you are using **form** tag more then one time asp.controls not working properly

Comment: I dont seem to be using form in this.